# Convert text back to HTML in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my JavaScript code I'm converting some HTML to text, such that I'm able to POST the text to my controller without using attributes such as `[Validation(false)]` etc. Specifically, I'm doing this in my JavaScript:

```
var emailBody = $('#SomeID').html();
var result = $('#SomeID').html(emailBody).text();
```

The `result` value holds around 10 lines of text including line breaks `/n` etc.

I'm POST-ing this by doing:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("ControllerMethod", "Controller")', { formId: formValue, emailBody: result}, function (data) { ... }
```

My controller is able to receive the above text that is being POSTed. However, now that it's in the "backend" of the code, I need to convert this back to `HTML` somehow. How do I go about doing this? It's not terribly complex HTML that needs to be "restored" mainly `<p> <h3> <a href..>` tags.

Is there a quick way to do this? Otherwise I could escape it on the JavaScript end:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

and then do a similar inverse function in the backend.

I'm not really sure how to handle this problem in the best way.

Comment: methinks you want something like [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx) or [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Not exactly related, but `<p><h3>...` is invalid HTML, `p` can contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) only.

Comment: @Teemu it look a like just sample of tags :-)

Comment: @Grundy Yeah, but just in case it's real, the `h3`s would be taken out of the `p` in `innerHTML`, which might lead unexpected results when parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regex.Unescape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=net-5.0) to unescape every character in string.

You can use [Regex.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0) to escape every character in string.

Comment: So provided I use the escape function I described in my question, I could use Regex.Unescape in C# to get the HTML back?

Comment: Just by giving it the string passed into the controller it doesn't escape it properly. E.g. &lt; is left untouched